# How to get value of SCALAR(0x5bc3550) in perl

Tags: perl, variables, scalar

I am debugging OTRS and trying to log one of the variables into a text file to see what's going on..

When I do the following :

```
open(my $fhii, '>>', '/opt/mail-log/mailbody.txt');
print $fhii "Body :" . $Param{Body} . "\n";
```

It actually prints this in my file :

```
Body :SCALAR(0x5b64388)
```

I know its something pretty trivial for someone who knows whats going on, I am newbie to perl and I cant seem to find a reference on the net to get the value for what is inside the `$Param{Body}`.

Comment: It's a scalar reference. `${$Param{Body}}` will dereference it and get the actual value.

Comment: Tried it, still the same result.. Body -: SCALAR(0x5136200)

Comment: First thought is that you've got an odd data structure. Second thought is `use Data::Dump qw(pp);` at the top, and then `print $fhii pp(\%Param);` to find out what the hash actually looks like.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `print $fhii "Body :" . $Param{Body} . "\n";` - there's a dot and a double quote missing.

Comment: @zb226 Yes, but I would expect a syntax error in that case. I assume it's a copy-paste error rather than an actual problem, but maybe not!

Comment: @zb226, Yes that was a copy paste error..

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, `$Param{Body}` appears to be a reference to a scalar.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $body = "abc";
   my %Param = ( Body => \$body );
   say $Param{Body};
   say ${ $Param{Body} };
'
SCALAR(0x12e28a8)
abc
```